# Smooth switching between texture atlas animations

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

**How can I make smooth transitions between multiple animations on the same character without delay?**

I'm developing a game in iOS Swift with a jumping character. This character has a few animations, like the basic animation, the jump animation and a landing animation.

I set the texture atlas for every animation as follows:

```
    // Basic
    let surferBasicAnimatedAtlas = SKTextureAtlas(named: "surfer_basic.atlas")

    let numImages = surferBasicAnimatedAtlas.textureNames.count

    for var i=0; i<numImages; i++ {
        let surferBasicTextureName = "surfer_basic_000\(i)"
        self.surferBasicFrames.append(surferBasicAnimatedAtlas.textureNamed(surferBasicTextureName))
    }

    // Jump
    let surferJumpAnimatedAtlas = SKTextureAtlas(named: "surfer_jump.atlas")

    let numJumpImages = surferJumpAnimatedAtlas.textureNames.count

    for var i=0; i<numJumpImages; i++ {
        let surferJumpTextureName = "surfer_jump_000\(i)"
        self.surferJumpFrames.append(surferJumpAnimatedAtlas.textureNamed(surferJumpTextureName))
    }

    // Landing
    let surferLandingAnimatedAtlas = SKTextureAtlas(named: "surfer_landing.atlas")

    let numLandingImages = surferLandingAnimatedAtlas.textureNames.count

    for var i=12; i<numLandingImages; i++ {
        let surferLandingTextureName = "surfer_landing_000\(i)"
        self.surferLandingFrames.append(surferLandingAnimatedAtlas.textureNamed(surferLandingTextureName))
    }

    // Pick textures
    self.surferWalkingFrames = surferBasicFrames

    let firstFrame = surferWalkingFrames[0]
    self.character = SKSpriteNode(texture: firstFrame)

    self.character.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.animateWithTextures(surferWalkingFrames, timePerFrame: (1 / 30), resize: false, restore: true)), withKey:"surferBasic")
```

When I touch the screen the basic animation should stop and the jump animation should run, but it causes a delay. About one second after the touch the jump animation starts.

I've tried this:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

    self.character.removeActionForKey("surferBasic")

    self.surferWalkingFrames = surferJumpFrames
    self.character.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.animateWithTextures(surferWalkingFrames, timePerFrame: (1 / 30), resize: false, restore: true)), withKey:"surferJump")
}
```

**How can I make smooth transitions between multiple animations on the same character without delay?**

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong, but it looks like (1 / 30) is your offender for a couple of reasons.

1. 1/30 will return an int and it will be 0
2. if you do 1.0/30.0 you will get a nice float like you want but it will be 0.03333333333333 and you are asking it two switch the texture 30 times a second. That is rather fast and you may not even see it change.

I would try .2 first and see if that changes anything if it does then it is just a matter of finding how fast you need to change the texture.

Hopefully that helps.

Comment: It did make the transition smoother. There's no 'freeze' between the transition anymore. However, the actual jump animation still starts a second late. So your answer helped partially! Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: @NGAFD When you say it starts a second late does that mean you see the basic animation a little longer or it doesn't animate at all for a second? The only other thing I can think of is setting restore to false.

Comment: I see the basic animation for a second longer!

Comment: @NGAFD  the code you provided everything else looks fine. I would double check to make sure you don't have anything else in touches begin or update that could cause this. Other issues could be the first couple textures in the jump array looking similar to basic, restore to false might help, or  a difference from using self. but that isn't likely to make a difference.